# How to use CSS variable in `background-image` in Webpack?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, webpack-4, css-variables

I want to use this code in my SCSS file:

```
.x {
  --image: '/path/img.svg';
  background-image: url(var(--image));
}
```

But compilation fails with this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './--image'

Is there some trick to escape module resolving here?

---

Loaders in my Webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]',
  },
}, 
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {sourceMap: true},
    }, {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {sourceMap: true, config: {path: `./postcss.config.js`}},
    }, {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {sourceMap: true},
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
.x {
  --image: url(/path/img.svg);
  background-image: var(--image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring using a variable like this if you're not on vanilla css? You can just do:

```
$image = '/path/img.svg';

.x { 
  background-image: url($image);
}
```

*EDIT*:

as for straight up css, you have a syntax error, try this:

```css
.x {
  --image: '/path/img.svg';
  background-image: url(var(--image));
}
```

Comment: Because `--image: '/path/img.svg'` rule will be changed in HTML component inline styles.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I fixed the typo in my example. But in my real application reference to the variable is correct.

Comment: Next step: an image URI is in a href attribute on a link but I want to use it as a background image in a div. It seems that because attr() only works in content, it cannot be used to populate a variable that gets used in url(). Is there a way around this?